# Horizontal scroll on wheelEvent with shift too fast

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have 200 objects on the `MyView` that is derived from the `QGraphicsView`. I use the mouse wheel to scroll vertically, everything is nice and smooth. I think that is the Qt default implementation.

I implement the Shift + wheel to scroll horizontally, and the horizontal scroll bar jumps a huge step on a single wheel event - 10 times bigger than that on the vertical scroll bar.

Basically, the same wheel event drives the horizontal scroll bar 10 times farther than the vertical scroll bar.

How to slow down the horizontal scroll bar?

Well, I tried to reduce the original event's `angleDelta` value like this `event.angleDelta()/10` to generate a new wheel event and use the new event to drive the horizontal scroll bar. That works but seems to be too complicated.

I also notice it is the Shift modifier that affects the horizontal scroll bar behavior. If I do `self.horizontalBar().wheelEvent(event)` without the Shift modifier, the horizontal bar scrolling is 10 times slower. That is weird. Why does pressing Shift change the horizontal scrolling behavior?!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsTextItem, QApplication, QWheelEvent, Qt


class MyView(QGraphicsView):
    def wheelEvent(self, event: QWheelEvent):
        if event.modifiers() == Qt.ShiftModifier:
            self.horizontalScrollBar().wheelEvent(event)
        else:
            self.verticalScrollBar().wheelEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view = MyView(scene)

    # Generate 200 objects, 100 on x and 100 on y.
    for i in range(100):
        obj_on_x = QGraphicsTextItem("X" + str(i))
        obj_on_x.setX(i * 100)
        scene.addItem(obj_on_x)

        obj_on_y = QGraphicsTextItem("Y" + str(i))
        obj_on_y.setY(i * 100)
        scene.addItem(obj_on_y)

    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't help. Those properties don't have any effect on how the horizontal bar handles the QWheelEvent, which essentailly delivers an angleDelta to Qt. The key problem is that the horizontal bar does not work while the vertical bar wokrs perfectly. I did not do anything special for the vertical bar.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to accomplish this is to trigger a
[`SliderSingleStepAdd` or `SliderSingleStepSub`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#SliderAction-enum)
action using the [`triggerAction`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#triggerAction) function.

These seem to move at an appropriate scroll speed since it applies whatever delta would naturally be used.

```py
def wheelEvent(self, event: QtGui.QWheelEvent):

    scrollbar = self.verticalScrollbar()
    if (event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier):
        scrollbar = self.horizontalScrollBar()

    action = QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderSingleStepAdd
    if (event.angleDelta().y() > 0):
        action = QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderSingleStepSub

    scrollbar.triggerAction(action)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to slow down the two scrollbars, I would interact with them changing their values like this (in my code, I moved the scrollbars horizontally with Ctrl and vertically with Shift):

```
def wheelEvent(self, event):

    delta = event.angleDelta().y()

    if event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier:
        x = self.horizontalScrollBar().value()
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(x - delta)

    elif event.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
        y = self.verticalScrollBar().value()
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(y + delta)
```